# How to populate UIPickerView with Parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, parse-platform

I'm stuck. I have called the PFQuery and I NSlog my "Categories"
and it all comes fine in the debugger area.

Where I'm having trouble is using this data to populate my UIPickerView from Parse.com.

Here is what I came up with.

Note that I have the necessary methods already for the Picker, I just need to use the data from parse to populate it.

_pickerData is a NSArray that populates the picker and I thought I could equal to objects to populate but this didn't work.

**EDIT: What I have so far...**

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Categories"];
    [query whereKeyExists:@"Category"];
    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            _pickerData = objects;

            NSLog(@"%@",objects);
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"error");
        }
    }];


    self.categoryPicker.dataSource = self;
    self.categoryPicker.delegate = self;


}


// The number of columns of data
- (int)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

// The number of rows of data
- (int)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return _pickerData.count;
}

// The data to return for the row and component (column) that's being passed in
- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return _pickerData[row];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, as said above you need to reload your pickerView after your query finds the objects and loads the array. Also note this is an array of PFObjects, and you must use a key-value for the title, you can't just plug in a PFObject for the titleForRow: DataSource call.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.categoryPicker.dataSource = self;
    self.categoryPicker.delegate = self;

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Categories"];
    [query whereKeyExists:@"Category"];
    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            _pickerData = objects;
            [self.categoryPicker reloadAllComponents];
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"error");
        }
    }];
}


// The number of columns of data
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

// The number of rows of data
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return _pickerData.count;
}

// The data to return for the row and component (column) that's being passed in
- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    PFObject *object = _pickerData[row];
    //Assuming "Category" is a string here for your title
    return object[@"Category"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reload your picker view after assign `objects` to `_pickerData`

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Categories"];
[query whereKeyExists:@"Category"];
[query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        _pickerData = objects;

      [_categoryPicker reloadData];

      NSLog(@"%@",objects);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"error");
    }
}];
```

Comment: its not working, the uipickerview is called 'categoryPicker' but the nsarray that populates the picker is 'pickerData'

Comment: reload categoryPicker and assign objects into pickerData

Comment: how would i go about doing that?

Comment: still doesnt let me use reloadData, i can only use reloadAllComponents and when i do app crashes.

Comment: what exception you are getting?

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PFObject copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xaaa6970'

Answer (score 0):

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Categories"];
    [query whereKeyExists:@"Category"];
    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            _pickerData = objects;

             // update pickerView
             [categoryPicker reloadAllComponents];

            NSLog(@"%@",objects);
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"error");
        }
    }];
```

Use `[categoryPicker reloadAllComponents];` to update the pickerView after the data is loaded.

**Edit:**

Set delegate & source
// Connect data

```
self.categoryPicker.dataSource = self;
self.categoryPicker.delegate = self;
```

Add methods:

```
// The number of columns of data
- (int)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

// The number of rows of data
- (int)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return _pickerData.count;
}

// The data to return for the row and component (column) that's being passed in
- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return _pickerData[row];
}
```

Comment: its not working, the uipickerview is called 'categoryPicker' but the nsarray that populates the picker is 'pickerData'

Comment: use pickerData as dataSource for pickerView

Comment: my uipickerView is called "categoryPicker" so dont i need to call the datasource that?

Comment: also when i try typing [pickerData reloadAllComponents]; xcode gives me an error.

Comment: it's _[categoryPicker reloadAllComponents];_

Comment: i get this when i try that 

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PFObject copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xaaa6970'

Comment: use methods instead of _PFObject *object = _pickerData[row]; return object[@"Category"];_ like _PFObject *object = [_pickerData objectAtIndex:row]; and [object objectForKey:@"Category"];